# Can I require that all GitHub commits come from a pull request?

Tags: git, github, githooks

I'd like to enforce that all commits to master come from a pull request.  We don't want commits directly to master if it doesn't come through a pull request.

Is there any way to do this?  Can this be achieved via a server hook, for example?

Answer (score 1):

You can - see https://help.github.com/articles/about-protected-branches/ 
It applies to public repos on, if you pay for GH, for private repos too.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you want that behaviour for github pull requests! As github does not offer serverside hooks, you have to do it on your own and on your machine!

If you apply github pull requests to your repo, it could possibly happen that there is a fast-forward. And as you don't want this, you should do the following:

1. Add a new remote (the repository which has the commits for the pull request)
2. Fetch the new remote
3. Merge the appropriate branch with `--no-ff`
4. Push it to your github account.

This would ensure that your master has only merges, even if there could be a fast forward. You can afterwards remove the remote.

If you share your repository with others (public write access) you are not able to enforce this. But anyway, I would not allow others to access my repository!

---

If you want to ensure nobody is able to commit to the master branch (on every fork/clone of the repository), you should write a hook (client side), which checks the branch and aborts the commit if the branch is master. Please note that each user has to enable the hook himself by default and every user is able to do a commit without running hooks!